# Print a character string below each other

Tags: c

I'm trying to do, a program that prints a string like this

```
char str[] = "This is a test string";
```

And then get this output

```
This
is
a
test
string
```

All this without using neither loop nor recursion. It is possible to do this?

Comment: Google for `strtok`. Regarding the "without using loop nor recursion", this should *always* be possible since loops can be unrolled.

Comment: How about using regular expression?

Comment: It cannot be done as either a library call or yourself will need to use a loop (or recursion)

Comment: You *could* use `goto`...

Comment: There is no function that does it automatically. A loop is there when you print a string - it's either in your code or in theirs, but strings are printed one character at a time.

Comment: could hack the console driver to interpret space as newline, modify the console driver, recompile kernel, reboot, compile source as is.. ? /s

Comment: @cad: as you would with goto

Comment: @Kevin See my answer.

Comment: you could use use the shell command tr, invoked with the system() function and piping the original string into the tr utility and running the output to stdout. Where tr is used to translate a space to a newlline\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments to this answer, `goto` is just a bad replacement for `for`, `while`, etc. Technically, it is a loop, so writing the program **without looping is pretty much impossible**.

Furthermore, as others have mentioned, `printf` and similar screen I/O functions most probably also uses a loop, so "All this without using loop nor recursion [...]" should be pretty hard.

Writing the "printing each word on a seperate line" part as a general solution<sup>1</sup> could be done using the `goto` keyword, though. The following program replaces every occurence of `' '` with a `\n` and prints the string afterwards:

```
size_t i = 0;
loop_beg:
    if (!str[i])
        goto loop_end;
    if (str[i] == ' ')
        str[i] = '\n';
    ++i;
    goto loop_beg;
loop_end:

printf("%s\n", str);
```

Note: *this probably compiles down to a loop at the Assembly level and is then roughly equivalent to the `for`-loop construct in C but I'll ignore that.*

Related to that, you should read (or at least skim) Edsger Dijsktra's (Dutch guy, invented semaphores, co-wrote the OS "THE") ["Go To Statement Considered Harmful"](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> to just print every word of **this particular** string on one line each neither of this is required, obviously.

Comment: well, it's still a loop. I don't think OPs restrictions are particularly realistic.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht Depends on what you consider a loop. To me, a loop is `do` + `while`, `while`, or `for`, a `goto` (equivalent to an x86 `jmp` instruction) is a `goto`.

Comment: Semantics aside, that is definitely a loop and I do think the OP set an extremely unrealistic goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strtok` for this  **but it is implemented with the help of loop** and its pretty neat

```
char str[] ="This is a test string";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");  <-- delimiter to seperate the string
  }
```

Comment: It mentions without a loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "         this     is a string";

    char *ptr = str;

    bool init = 0;

    int n = 0;

BlackLabel:
    if( *ptr == '\0' )
         goto exit;

    n++;

    if( *ptr == ' ' )
        n = 0;

    if( n == 1 )
    {
        if( init )
        {
            putc('\n',stdout);
        }
    }

    if( n > 0 )
    {
        init = 1;
        printf("%c",*ptr);
    }

    *ptr++;

    goto BlackLabel;

exit:
    putc('\n',stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I propose to replace space with new line indicator.

```
public string f(string input)
{
 str = str.Replace(" ", "\n");
 return str;
}
```

This fuction will return text with each word one below another.

EDIT:
Note that this will be always used with loops. Even if not called directly, your application just must to go throught all characters in range.

Comment: The question is only tagged [c], currently.